# customizing info window for multiple markers

Tags: ios, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have seen the google developers video on custom info window for google maps ios sdk and got it. But how to use it when we have multiple markers. In my application i have to point 10 place and have to use that custom infowindow

Comment: That video shows how to display custom infowindow for one marker. But how to display when we have multiple like 10 to 15 markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, we just have to call the customInfoWindow class how many time we want with new set of parameters.

Comment: Could you provide some code how you solved this ? How your customInfoWindow implementation looks ?

Comment: @Steve i used the code provided in google developers live blog. here is the link https://developers.google.com/live/shows/864758637

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly if this is what the question was - but you can attach a piece of your own data to the marker using marker.userData.  You can make this anything you want - an NSDictionary for example.  In -markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *marker) you can retrieve the userData and based on that, you can decide what view you want to return.  Make sure the userData contains sufficient data to decide what your view should contain and you are good to go.